# Clock to use when giving presentations

Tags: clock

When I give presentations, I have to keep an eye on the clock to make sure my speech does not take more than alloted time, or in the end to know whether I can take more questions.

Looking at my watch is inconvenient, I would prefer my Android phone's large screen to:

- Just display the time (for example 14:28).
- Not go into standby mode.
- Hugest font possible, black on white, landscape.

Sounds trivial. Is there such an app?
*Priority to free apps, biggest priority to open source apps.*

Comment: Make sure there is a hanging clock on the back of the audience. This promotes 'looking' at the audience and gives everyone a 'timeframe'. I'd also ask someone to keep track of the time if you need a really tight timing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Digital Clock](http://www.androlib.com/android.application.com-socialnmobile-clock-digital-jqnj.aspx) does *almost* everything you ask. Ignore the rubbish picture from the page, it is a full-screen clock with white text on black and it's free.

To configure it as you need, launch the app, then open the settings (tap the screen to open the options then tap **Settings**) then set:

- **Clock**->**Screen timeout** to unchecked.
- **Clock**->**Orientation** to **Landscape**.
- **Time & Date**->**Show date** to unchecked.

You can also adjust the time format and colour if you wish. The time is about half the screen height, but I can easily read it on my phone from more than 20ft away so that may not be a problem.

Comment: Perfect. After the easy configuration steps you described, it does exactly what I was looking for :-)

Comment: The link is dead.

Answer (score 3):

I use [Ovo timer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.ilumbo.ovo): a minimalist app to set your timer by dragging an arc on your screen. Also, you can set time by voice (it needs Internet connection for this). It runs on Android 2.1 and up. The only con I've found is that it only supports times not greater than 1 hour.

[image: Draw an arc to set time] [image: Time running - Portrait] [image: Set time by voice]

About what you're asking for:

- *Just display the time (for example 14:28).* **Check**.
- *Not go into standby mode.* **Check**: You can configure it to do so via Preferences.
  [image: Preferences: Stay Awake]
- *Hugest font possible, black on white, landscape.* **Close enough**: It rotates as your device does. Also the red/white arc animation gives you a clue about remaining time.
  [image: Time running - Landscape]
- *Free app.* **Check**.
- *Open source app.* **I think not**.

Comment: +1 Not exactly what I was thinking, but Visually showing remaining time as a circle is a great idea!

Answer (score 1):

I use
[Stopwatch & Timer](http://www.appbrain.com/app/stopwatch-timer/com.sportstracklive.stopwatch)
 Goes full screen when you change into landscape orientation, also I used the lap times when we had to give a team presentation.

Answer (score 1):

I use [Flow Timer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bimjay.flowtimer) for this, it displays the (countdown) time in the largest possible width in black on white (default).
Furthermore by default it just dims the screen but doesn't turn it off (in the settings there is a choice to keep it at "bright", that is, to not even dim the screen a bit).
Landscape mode (even tablet) as well.

You can also add several timers after each other for different parts of the presentation. No interaction required, it just makes a small beep (configurable) and continues/finishes.

Full disclosure: I'm the author